# Javascript redirect using windows.locaton.href OR windows.locaton.replace is not working. Error: window not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have looked at all of the questions around windows.locaton.href and windows.locaton.replace not working, but still can't figure out why this redirect is not working in JavaScript. There are two JS functions I am calling when a button is clicked with submit.

```
 <input type="submit"
```

onclick="NotifyUserOfNewBudgets('@Field1');redirect2MainLookup('@primaryFilename');" 
class="SaveChangeButton" value="Create New Budget">

The two functions are defined in Javascript as:

```
<script>

function NotifyUserOfNewBudgets(val) {
    alert("New Budget will be saved. NewVal=" + val);
    var ireturn;

    document.getElementById("NewBudgetID").value = val;
    document.getElementById("formMode").value = "Update";
}

function redirect2MainLookup(primaryFilename) {
    var loc = window.location.pathname;
    var host = document.location.host;
    var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));

    //Replace the word Edit with blank so this redirects correctly
    var newdir = dir.replace("NewBudget", "");

    var newpath = host + newdir + primaryFilename;
    alert('newpath location = http://' + newpath);
    try {
        windows.locaton.href = "http://" + newpath;
         //window.location.replace('http://' + newpath);
    } catch (err) { alert("Error: " + err);}

}
</script>
```

The error I get in the try()catch() is  windows is not defined and then is stays on the same page.  I get the same error using windows.locaton.replace() too. I have lots of pages doing redirects, can't figure out why this one fails.

Comment: Have you tried using windows.location instead of window.location? Especially in the var loc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of spelling mistakes. `window` is the object you are looking to reference. `location` is the property you are looking to access. Right now, you are using `windows.locaton`. `windows` is not a thing, nor is `locaton`. Keep an eye on `undefined` errors, they can tell you a lot about the state of your code.

Comment: Thanks Daxton, I corrected those and nonplussed I didn't see these.  I have tried this again with window.location.href = "http://" + newpath; and  window.location.replace("http://" + newpath);  and the redirect still does not happen.  Question: Is it possible to redirect after saving values to a form with a submit?

Comment: I don't think I can submit values and drop back through the form based on other posts I have seen, but wish I could get a definitive answer on this.  So, going another route, I have added the following up in the C# code:   
    Response.Redirect("~/Budget/ListBudgetsByFiscalYear");    This redirects to the new page after I run the code to update the database with new values after the post occurs.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, if you are using MVC, redirecting after a `form` submit needs to happen at the `Controller` level, because a `form` submit **refreshes the page**. If you want to redirect after a post, you would need to use something like jQuery's AJAX by posting your form data, then redirecting after a successful response.